# Custom validation [AngualrJS]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I was writing code for implementing validation on a input text box. Which should allow the user to enter only numbers. Almost succeeded in implementing this functionality, but faced one difficulty : 
**I'm not able to delete the last character entered.**

```
app.directive('num', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, el, attrs, ctrl) {

        var lastValidValue;
        var NUMBER_REGEXP = /^[0-9]+$/;
        ctrl.$parsers.push(function (value) {
            console.log('inside parsers')
            console.log("Last " + lastValidValue + ", View " + ctrl.$viewValue + ", model " + ctrl.$viewValue);
            if (NUMBER_REGEXP.test(value)) {
                console.log('true')
                lastValidValue = value;
            }
            else {
                ctrl.$viewValue = lastValidValue;
                ctrl.$render();
            }
            console.log("Last " + lastValidValue + ", View " + ctrl.$viewValue + ", model " + ctrl.$viewValue);
            return lastValidValue;
        });
    }
}
```

})

Please help me to tackle the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing `if (NUMBER_REGEXP.test(value))` to `if (NUMBER_REGEXP.test(value) || value == '')`

Comment: That worked. Thanks a lot. Could u pls tell me what I did wrong?

Comment: So you coded the directive so that it only allows numbers (your regex pattern)...empty or '' doesn't     count as a number so you have to consider/allow for that case.